# Mooc java part 1 Part05_15.Archive checking if objects in arraylist contain a value

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contains

It seems my program wont check that the variable from the object is contained in the arraylist. When ran with tmc it fails 2 tests. Both items with the same identifier are added to the arraylist when i should only have unique identifiers added in the arraylist.

Here is what MOOC asks for:

Modify the program so that after entering the items, each item is printed at most once. Two items should be considered the same if their identifiers are the same (there can be variation in their names in different countries, for instance).
If the user enters the same item multiple times, the print uses the item that was added first.

ArchiveTest printingTwoEqualItemsOnlyPrintsOneItem  Fail

With the input:identifier
item2
identifier
item2

the print had 2 items:
[identifier: item2, identifier: item2]
The expected number of items was 1.
Check your program -- also ensure that the only place you use colons in is when you print items.

ArchiveTest printingTwoItemsWithDifferentNamesButSameIdentifiersOnlyContainsOneItem     Fail

With the input:identifier
item1
identifier
item2

the print had 2 items:
[identifier: item1, identifier: item2]
The expected number of items was 1.
Check your program -- also ensure that the only place you use colons in is when you print items.

```
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Item> archive = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Identifer?(empty will stop)");
            String identifier = scanner.nextLine();
            if (identifier.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Name?(empty will stop)");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            if (name.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
            Item item1 = new Item(identifier, name);
            if (archive.contains(item1.identifier)){
                continue;
            }
            archive.add(item1);


        }
        System.out.println("==items==");
        for (Item item : archive
        ) {
            System.out.println(item.toString());

        }


    }
}
```

```
public class Item {
    String identifier;
    String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return identifier + ": " + name;
    }

    Item(String i, String n){
        this.identifier = i;
        this.name = n;

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use an `ArrayList`?  This would make far more sense if you used some kind of `Map<String,Item>`, keyed by the identifier.

Comment: I havent yet learned to use hashmaps within this course, hmm but i will try to implement this instead, i think my code goes wrong here (archive.contains(item1.identifier)), im not sure that is correct way.

Comment: Well, your problem is that `archive` is a list of Items, but you're looking in it for an identifier, which is a String.  So that `contains` call is comparing apples to oranges, or at least Items to Strings.  There are a few different ways to fix this though.